# $.getJSON not sending parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an application where, the moment the user hits an element, it opens a Bootstrap modal containing other options he can select. When it's opened, the modal fires an AJAX request to the server to fetch the options pertaining to that element.

The `$.getJSON` function is being called like this:

```
$("#modal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {


    $.getJSON('webservice.php', { type: 'loadOptions', optid: $(this).attr("rowid") }, function(data) {
      var li = $("<li rowid=\"" + index + "\"/>");

      li.append("<center><h3>" + value.description + "</h3></center>");
      li.append("<center><span id=\"sms\"></span>");
      li.append("<hr/>");
      li.append("<center>US$ " + value.price.toFixed(2) + "/month</center>");

      $("#modal ul").append(li);
    });
});
```

This is the button:

```
<li rowid="4" class="btn-optionals btn-optional-sms">Optional SMS Package</li>
```

When the user clicks on the list element, the modal opens up, the AJAX request is fired but it only sends the `type` parameter. I have tried putting its value on the query string, tried associating the `optid` to a variable then putting it on the data object, all to no avail.

Do I really have to build the `$.ajax` function manually for this to work?

Comment: `$(this)` refers to your modal not `li`

Comment: the syntax you use is good to send the parameters, did you check in your dev tools network panel if the request is really missing the optid param ? did you try putting a console.log before the call to ensure $(this).attr("rowid") is not empty ?

Comment: @Matt.k makes sense.

@user3 yes, I checked, it was only sending the `type` param. But @Matt.k has a point.

Comment: Show your HTML, with how the `li` is related to the `modal`.